# Confusion related to the calculation of autocovariance

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have a confusion related to the calculation of autocovariance

Suppose

$X_t =  \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

Then how the autocovariance

$E(X_{t+n}X_t) - \mu^2 = \frac{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2}{(1-\phi^2)}\phi^{|n|}$

I am referring to this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below, I use the same notations as those from the wikipedia link that you provided.

Let's start with the simplest case:

\begin{align*}
\textrm{Cov}(X_{t+1}, X_{t}) 
  & \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \textrm{Cov}(\varphi X_{t} + \epsilon_{t+1}, X_{t}) \\
  & \stackrel{\textrm{linearity}}{=} \varphi \, \textrm{Cov}(X_{t}, X_{t}) + \textrm{Cov}(\epsilon_{t+1}, X_{t}) \\
  & \stackrel{\textrm{Cov}(\epsilon_{t+1}, X_{t}) = 0}{=} \varphi \, \textrm{Var}(X_{t}) \\
  & \stackrel{\textrm{cf. wikipedia}}{=} \varphi \, \frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{1 - \varphi^2} \cdot
\end{align*}

OK, let's go one step further:
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Cov}(X_{t+2}, X_{t}) 
  & = \textrm{Cov}(\varphi X_{t+1} + \epsilon_{t+2}, X_{t}) \\
  & = \varphi \, \textrm{Cov}(X_{t+1}, X_{t})  \\
  & = \varphi^2 \frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{1 - \varphi^2} \cdot
\end{align*}

Now, the general case becomes clear:
$$
\textrm{Cov}(X_{t+n}, X_{t}) = \varphi^n \frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{1 - \varphi^2} \cdot
$$
Here $n \geq 0$, but the same can be done for $n < 0$.

If you want something more rigorous, following these lines, it is now easy to write a proof by induction

Answer (score 0):

See page 85-86 in the book "Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R examples" by R.H. Shumway and D.S. Stoffer.

If you iterate backwards $k$ times then you get:

$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t=\phi^k X_{t-k}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\phi^j \epsilon_{t-j}$

Hints:

$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t=\phi(\phi x_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t-1})+\epsilon_t$ (and so on...)

Continuing in this way you get:

$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\phi^j \epsilon_{t-j}$

So, $E(X_t)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\phi^j E(\epsilon_{t-j})=0$

Using this you can easily find the autocovariance function as:

$\gamma(n)=cov(X_{t+n},X_t)=E[(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\phi^j \epsilon_{t+n-j})(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\phi^k \epsilon_{t-k})]$

Expanding this gives you what you require. And also remember, $\gamma(n)=\gamma(-n)$. Thus comes the absolute sign.